# Cannot restrict TFS Area Path selection

Tags: team-foundation-server

Say I have the following TFS area path:

```
Fruit
    --Apple
    --Banana
    --Grapes
```

Apple, Banana, and Grapes are children of Fruit.  How do I require a selection of one of the 3 children of the area path so the user doesn't select "Fruit" and move on?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the detailed instruction here: https://vsardata.blob.core.windows.net/projects/TFS%20Process%20Template%20%20Customization%20Guidance.pdf Section: Walkthrough-Scenario 3 -Area Path Depth validation

Steps:

1. Find restricted area ids.
2. Create a custom field with prohibited messages in your work item type.